# addresses of characters printed by cout

Tags: c++, c

I am printing the addresses of variables in the following code snippet.

```
int int1=3;
char ch1='f';
printf("address int1 %llX\n",&int1);
printf("address ch1 %llX\n",&ch1);
cout<<"address int1 "<<&int1<<endl;
cout<<"address ch1 "<<&ch1<<endl;
```

Here is the output:

```
address int1 7FFF47D7C0F0
address ch1 7FFF47D7C0E8
address int1 0x7fff47d7c0f0
address ch1 f@
```

My question is Why *cout* prints the contents of the character rather than its address in this example? However, *printf* displays the addresses as shown above. Furthermore, the following also displays the address correctly:

```
cout<<"address ch1 "<<(void*)&ch1<<endl;
```

Comment: Because you are passing `std::cout` a `char*`, which is is overloaded to read as a string literal.

Comment: `cout <<` is overloaded for `const void *` as well

Comment: you tell printf what to do exactly. Cout or the runtime gets the operator while the operator << is called it does not understand you want to print a pointer adress. Printing the adress of a void* is the only thing that makes sense, thats why it works.